# How to post premium and free version of a game to game center?

Tags: ios, game-center

I build an app with two different version. One with add integrated into it and another with premium version(without add). How to post my app in to game center.

Answer (score 1):

They have to appear separately on game center if they are two different apps. This is why you are encouraged to use in-app purchasing to add "premium" features.

Game Center is accessed via the bundle identifier, which must be unique to one application. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1):

> CFBundleIdentifier (String - iOS, Mac OS X) uniquely identifies the
>   bundle. Each distinct application or bundle on the system must have a
>   unique bundle ID. The system uses this string to identify your
>   application in many ways. For example, the preferences system uses
>   this string to identify the application for which a given preference
>   applies; Launch Services uses the bundle identifier to locate an
>   application capable of opening a particular file, using the first
>   application it finds with the given identifier; in iOS, the bundle
>   identifier is used in validating the application’s signature.

Comment: Can we able to post a single game into game center (free and permium )version with same bundle identifier for game center integration.